# How do I show json data into tableview using array in swift4?

Tags: json, swift

I try to show JSON data into tableview in swift 4. I wrote a code for that but I got an error and crashed my project

My code where my program crashed

```
let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments ) as! [String : NSArray] //crashed on this line
if let arrJSON = jsonResult["JsonArray"] {
    for index in 0...arrJSON.count-1 {
        let aObject = arrJSON[index] as! [String : AnyObject]
        self.array.append(aObject["name"] as! String) as! String
    }
}
```

and I got an error.

> Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString'  to 'NSArray'.

How do I solve that please tell me where do I find a correct way to show son data on tableview because my json is complex

Please give me solution thx in advance

Comment: do you know how to use Alamofire

Comment: Nop is it open source means use at any project?

Comment: you can easily parse your json into tableView by using this, want to know ?

Comment: yes sure but I have only one doubt, is it open licence or not? and where do I get how to use alamofire to parse json?

Comment: @V_rohit For the question the tool to deserialize the JSON is irrelevant.

Comment: Can you post your JSON ? You are expecting an array but its crashing as you have a string instead.

Comment: https://www.appcoda.com/alamofire-beginner-guide/ use this link to learn

Comment: @vadian, maybe Sir but its good for him to learn

Comment: @V_rohit Thank you for link :)

Comment: Anytime :) but search first before you ask a question otherwise you get a downvote.

Comment: @GoodSp33d.                                                                       {
   Family =     [
                {
            VoterId = 123456;
            PanId = M0001;
        },
                {
            VoterId  = 123456;
            PanId = M0001;
        }
    ];
    Name = M0001;
    BitrthDate = "8 Dec 2017";
}

Comment: @V_rohit Actually you can learn much more without using those third party libraries.

Comment: @vadian, yes Sir we can but if you saw the code we are using library just to parse json and we still need to write our code to get data from json :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you will get the data in the same format you are parsing ( [ String: [ [ String : AnyObject] ] ] ). Then you can use following pattern:

> Use "options: [ ]", rather than using "options: .allowFragments"
>
> Also try with "options: .mutableLeaves" & "options: .mutableContainers" if not succeed

```
    if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: [[String : AnyObject]]], let arrJSON = jsonResult["JsonArray"] {
        
        for index in 0...arrJSON.count - 1 {
            let aObject = arrJSON[index]
            if let name = aObject["name"] as? String {
                self.array.append(name)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use `""` rather than `"options: []"` and **never** use `.mutableLeaves` and `.mutableContainers` in Swift. Both options are pointless.

Comment: Yes @vadian , we do not need to use 'options: [ ]' as it is default initializer. `open class func jsonObject(with data: Data, options opt: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions = []) throws -> Any`
". I mentioned it just for understanding

Comment: sorry but it gives me jsonResult "nil"

Comment: @mab - can you share the json string?

Comment: @AnkitJayaswal.  { Family = [ { VoterId = 123456; PanId = M0001; }, { VoterId = 123456; PanId = M0001; } ]; Name = M0001; BitrthDate = "8 Dec 2017"; }

Comment: @mab - This is not a valid json. You can check here [https://jsonlint.com/](https://jsonlint.com/)